# Custom tailor the dropdown menu by select option tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My leader told me select option could not be fully custom-tailored. Therefore, I have to use ul li to make the following css style. http://jsfiddle.net/C5mTf/59/

Sorry, the following is partial css had to show per stackoverflow requirement

```
#menu ul:hover .item:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cbc5cd;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

The following are requirements:
1. at initial stage, the dropdown menu only show first item with rounded corners.
2. if moving mouse over menu, it will display all items with the whole box rounded corner. 
3. After clicking any item or leaving the menu, the dropdown menu will hide all items except selected one

Is there a way to use select and option tags to build the same css appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross browser rendering answer is no. There are some jquery plugins that do a lot of dom manipulation for selects, but your menu looks fine. You will end up wasting more time on trying to figure out how to make it look that way.